# Trigger didEnterRegion event only once, for multiple iBeacon with Different UUID, major and minor

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ibeacon

I need to, didEnterRegion and didExitRegion should callback only once, for multiple iBeacon with different uuid, major and minor value.

Grouping iBeacon in one Region, i have tried using region identifier but it's working only when two iBeacon have same UUID.

my question is

how to group multiple iBeacon in same region meanwhile, iBeacon have different-different UUIDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do that.   The way the `CLBeaconRegion` class is designed by Apple, you have to specify a single `ProximityUUID` that is shared by all `CLBeacon` instances to be detected by the region.

As a workaround, you can either rework your beacon identifiers so they all share the same `ProximityUUID` or you can use multiple regions.  But you are correct that if you have multiple regions, you will get multiple callbacks with beacons grouped by their `ProximityUUID`.